# SQL: how to do a join on array where all values have to be present?

Tags: sql

I have a table of person availabilities:

```
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
         | M | T | W | F | S | S |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
Olivier  |   |   |   |   | X | X |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
Georges  | X |   |   | X |   |   |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So I have three tables:

- availability
- person
- person_availability

I'm doing a query like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person p
JOIN person_availability pa
ON p.id=pa.person_id
JOIN availability a
ON a.id=pa.availability_id
WHERE p.id = ?
AND a.day in (?)
```

with dynamic parameters. Example: param1=`1` and param2=`(1,4,5)`

The problem is that this query returns rows of person that are available in *one of those* availabilities. How to change to have person that are available in **all** those availabilities `(1,4,5)`?

Comment: `GROUP BY person HAVING Count(*) = @number_of_days`

Comment: I'm already doing a group by based on `id` (my SQL is far more complex than the example I'm asking here)

Comment: Have a read of **[this discussion here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1696614-help-day-week-comparison-contact-availability.html)** about alternative designs that you may wish to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a `GROUP BY p.id` and then match it with an `HAVING COUNT(a.day)` equals to the number of values inside your `IN (?)`. This way you are making sure that you get values for each person that are inside your IN clause, and if you provide 3 values and your COUNT returns 3, you know that person has all the availabilities.

Like so:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person p
JOIN person_availability pa ON p.id = pa.person_id
JOIN availability a ON a.id = pa.availability_id
WHERE p.id = 1 AND a.day IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(a.day) = 3;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1703/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

Put your param2 into a temp table with this structure:

```
DECLARE @Days TABLE 
(
    Day INT
)
```

(Insert the days into the table)

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM person P
CROSS JOIN @Days D
-- Only include people where all the days are in their available days
WHERE D.Day IN
    (
        SELECT A.Day
        FROM availability A
        JOIN person_availability PA ON A.availability_id = PA.availability_id
        JOIN person P1 ON P1.person_id = PA.person_id
        WHERE P1.person_id = P.person_id
    )
AND P.person_id = PARAM1
```